# Is it possible to use regular expressions to find a pattern which is padded with zeros, and return the value without padding?

Tags: python, regex, zero-padding

I have a list of reference IDs which are alphanumeric. They have 3 digits which are zero-padded to the left, followed by a letter, followed by 3 more digits, again, zero padded to the left.

eg.

```
original_ref_list = ["005a004",
                     "018b003",
                     "007a029",
                     "105a015"]
```

As you can see, both sets of digits are padded with zeros. I want to get the same references without the zero padding on either side of the letter, but not to remove all zeros.

eg.

```
fixed_ref_list = ["5a4",
                  "18b3",
                  "7a29",
                  "105a15"]
```

I can do this by by searching for three regex patterns, combining the results and appending this to a list:

```
fixed_ref_list = list()
for i in original_ref_list:
    first_refpat = re.compile(r'[1-9]\d*[a-z]\d+')
    first_refpatiter = first_refpat.finditer(gloss[2])
    for first_ref_find in first_refpatiter:
        first_ref = first_ref_find.group()
        second_refpat = re.compile(r'[a-z]\d+')
        second_refpatiter = second_refpat.finditer(first_ref)
        for second_ref_find in second_refpatiter:
            second_ref = second_ref_find.group()[1:]
            third_refpat = re.compile(r'[1-9]\d*')
            third_refpatiter = third_refpat.finditer(second_ref)
            for third_ref_find in third_refpatiter:
                third_ref = third_ref_find.group()
    fixed_ref_list.append(first_ref[:-len(second_ref)] + third_ref)
```

But this seems like an awkward solution. Is there a built in way to return only part of a regex pattern, or to remove the padding before returning the result? Alternatively, is there any way to do what I want that's less messy?

Comment: Are there always two digits in your string? e.g `005a` and `004`, or `018b` and `003`?

Comment: Not always, I've boiled the problem down for the sake of asking the question. I can except the type of references that aren't in this format and treat them differently.

Comment: Yes, add them to question please, along with the expected output.

Comment: They're not necessary. I only want to know how to clean the part of the code that deals with this type. The two answers below work very nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just group your matches using parenthesis like this:

```
re.match('([0-9a-f]{3})([0-9a-f])([0-9a-f]{3})', '005a004').groups()
> ('005', 'a', '004')
```

Now you have a tuple to work with. To remove the zeros in the beginning, you can match all the 0s using the `^` operator, which marks the beginning of a string and replace them with an empty string `''`:

```
re.sub('^0+', '', '004')
> '4'
```

That should give you all you need to make this more compact and readable.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension

```
fixed_ref_list  = [str(int(x[:3])) + x[3] + str(int(x[4:])) for x in original_ref_list]
```

Result

```
print(fixed_ref_list)
```

Output

```
["5a4",
 "18b3",
 "7a29",
 "105a15"]
```

Explanation

Assuming zero padding is on digits 0-9, use int(...) to remove the zero padding in the field

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following pattern `"0+` and substitute it with `"`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/D21BEF/1).

Be careful, as you have not said what do you want to happen to the last case [here](https://regex101.com/r/D21BEF/2).

In the case you want to substitute the full hex number `"00000"` into `"0"`, you have

```
"0*([0-9a-fA-F]+)"
```

as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/D21BEF/3).